# Django - Filter by Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm

I have 2 models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=150)

class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name='ass')
```

I can use this command to get a Project with all its Assets, it's cool.

```
proj = Project.objects.get(pk='QQ')
```

But I just want to get a Project with a specific Asset, this is my command:

```
proj = Project.objects.get(pk='QQ', ass__pk=50)
```

But it still returns all Assets. Then I turn on the SQL debug mode and find Django runs 2 SQLs.

1. It executes 'SELECT project.* FROM project INNER JOIN asset ON ... WHERE project.pk='QQ' AND asset.pk=50
2. It executes 'SELECT asset.* FROM asset WHERE asset.project = 'QQ'

I think the 1st SQL is enough, I have no idea why 2nd SQL is executed.
I use Django 4.2 with Python 3.8.10, can anybody help it?

**Update:**
I found both Zaburba and my code only execute 1st SQL, and because I use Django REST framework, I execute the 2 commands later.

```
serializer = ProjectWithAssetSerializer(proj) # don't execute any SQL
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) # Execute 2nd SQL
```

When I try to access `serializer.data`, it try to query again. And the following is serializers.py. Is it the root cause to execute the 2nd SQL? But I need to reply the result, if I don't use serializer, how to do it?

```
class ProjectWithAssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ass = AssetDataSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'

class AssetDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Assetdata
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add extra field to ModelSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459721/add-extra-field-to-modelserializer)

Answer (score 0):

This will perform one query :) sorry for the confusion

```py
>>> asset = Asset.objects.select_related('project').get(pk=50, project__name='test')
>>> project = asset.project
>>> print(project.id)
1
>>> print(len(connection.queries))
1
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns 
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'ass'. Choices are: (none). And if I only change 'select_related' to 'prefetch_related', it still gets all assets.

Comment: I made an error, sorry xD, but I've already found a potential solution
```python
>>> asset = Asset.objects.select_related('project').get(pk=50, project__name='test')
>>> project = asset.project
>>> print(project.id)
1
>>> print(len(connection.queries))
1

```
btw prefetch_related always performs one more query

Comment: Your code works, and my code works too. I find the root cause seems that I assess serialzier.data, can you check my update in the original post?